# Active Directory Authentication in MVC5 is not persisting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory

I was following Chris Schiffhauer's excellent tutorial on MVC5 authentication with Active Directory, [link here](http://www.schiffhauer.com/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/).

Anyways, I've followed his instructions, and upon successful authentication, it redirects to home/index. I know AD is working because if I use a bad password, the redirect doesn't happen and it presents an error on the login page, which is supposed to happen. The issue is... Upon redirection to the home page, the auth is lost. I still have the option to log in which is wrong. Other than the inclusion of the AD auth, I'm just using the MVC site template from VS2013. I can provide plenty more code if necessary. Ideas?

**AccountController.cs (edited)**

```
 if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {


            log.Info("User " + model.UserName + " is authenticated.");
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);





            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe).Value); //ticket creation/decryption is successful

            GenericIdentity id = new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name, "LdapAuthentication"); // id is successful

            log.Info("ticket :" + ticket.Name);

            // This principal will flow throughout the request.
            GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, null); //making the principal works

            // Attach the new principal object to the current HttpContext object


            log.Info("principal :" + principal.Identity.Name);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = principal; // this doesn't seem to work.


            if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return this.Redirect(returnUrl);
            }

            return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

**Login.cshtml**

```
...snipped for brevity...
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                    <hr/>
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new {@class = "col-md-3 control-label"})
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "col-md-3 control-label"})
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {@class = "form-control"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                }
 ...snipped for brevity...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're user is never assigned to the context. After you navigate to a other view, the user is lost.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Forms-Authentication-Active-Directory.aspx) about using Forms Authentication with Active Directory.

As you can see in the tutorial this is the crucial part:

```
// Extract the forms authentication cookie
string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
if(null == authCookie)
{
// There is no authentication cookie.
return;
}

FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;
try
{
      authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      // Log exception details (omitted for simplicity)
      return;
}
if (null == authTicket)
{
      // Cookie failed to decrypt.
      return;
}

// Create an Identity object
GenericIdentity id = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name,"LdapAuthentication");

// This principal will flow throughout the request.
GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, null);

// Attach the new principal object to the current HttpContext object
Context.User = principal;
```

Comment: I really want to mark this as the answer because This sounds about right but we are not quite there yet. I have edited the accountcontroller.cs to reflect the added lines you suggested. The login is still not persisting. Check the comments in my code to see what I mean.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I found the issue. You pointed me in the right direction so you get the bounty. I was not capturing the  Application_AuthenticateRequest event in global.asax. If anyone comes across this thread, see this MSDN posting:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same problem and I used MVC 5. I searched for the **Application_AuthenticateRequest** event handler in *global.aspx* but it wasn't there then I manually added the event handler and problem solved!